# need to update first non null field_x in non-normalised table

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table that I have to work with.
[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bd8c7)

Basically, it is a product that stores up to 10 barcodes for a product code (simplified example). At any time, any number of those 10 barcode fields might have a value.
I have another table that has a list of product code and barcode, and need to add these to the product barcode table.

I need to perform an update so that any of the barcodes in barcodes_to_import are appended to the product_barcode table, into the first non null barcode column.

```
table product_barcodes

product_Code    barcode_1  barcode_2  barcode_3 barcode_4  barcode_5
ABC             1          2          3
BCD             4          

table barcodes_to_import

product_code    barcode
ABC             7
BCD             8
```

Expected output:

```
product_Code    barcode_1  barcode_2  barcode_3 barcode_4  barcode_5
ABC             1          2          3         7
BCD             4          8
```

Comment: Could you please edit your question and add sample input and expected output?

Comment: So if a product has more than one barcode, which one of them should be in barcodes_to_import table? can one product have multiple rows with different barcodes in barcodes_to_import table?

Comment: `barcodes_to_import` basically lists any new barcodes that need to be merged into the product_barcodes table. So there can be multiple barcodes for the same product in the `barcodes_to_import` table, and these need to be updated into the `product_barcodes` table into the `barcode_x` fields.

Answer (score 0):

create table product_barcodes(product_Code varchar(10),barcode_1 int,barcode_2 int,barcode_3 int
,barcode_4 int,barcode_5 int,barcode_6 int,barcode_7 int,barcode_8 int,barcode_9 int,barcode_10 int)

create table barcodes_to_import(product_code varchar(10),barcode int)

--Inserted Sample values as below

SELECT * FROM product_barcodes
SELECT * FROM barcodes_to_import

--Output Query

;with cte
as
(
select product_code,data,col_name
from product_barcodes
unpivot
(
data for col_name in (
barcode_1,barcode_2,barcode_3,barcode_4,barcode_5
,barcode_6,barcode_7,barcode_8,barcode_9,barcode_10
)
) upvt
)
,cte1
as
(
select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY product_code ORDER BY col_name) as rn
from
(
select product_code, data,col_name from cte
union all
select product_code,barcode,'barcode_z' as col_name from barcodes_to_import
) t
)
select
product_Code
,SUM([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcCXh.jpg)) as barcode_1
,SUM([2]) as barcode_2
,SUM([3]) as barcode_3
,SUM([4]) as barcode_4
,SUM([5]) as barcode_5
,SUM([6]) as barcode_6
,SUM([7]) as barcode_7
,SUM([8]) as barcode_8
,SUM([9]) as barcode_9
,SUM([10]) as barcode_10

from cte1
PIVOT
(
AVG(data) for rn in ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcCXh.jpg),[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])
) pvt
GROUP BY product_Code  [image]